# "Zu+dem+pp", and its relationship with Latin grammar

Tags: grammar-identification, past-participle

Considering the following phrase --

> I gave myself a present for having passed the test.

> Ich mir zum bestandenen Examen geschenkt.

Is this analysis of *bestandenen* OK?

> past participle + en (=adjective ending)

This is like Latin, right?

> postum christum natum

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your analysis of "zum bestandenen Examen" is correct. It's like "post christum natum" in latin.

The sentence is missing a predicate and an object, one way to complete it would be:

> Ich habe mir zum bestandenen Examen etwas geschenkt.